# Why cant map the url to my request handler

Tags: python, regex, google-app-engine

```
('/\d+\?fmt=json',JsonHandler)

class JsonHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write("hello")
```

Hey, I am using google app engine python and tring to map the url to my request handler. The url is digits followed by ?fmt=json, but it just doesnt print out "hello" and the regex test returns true, say 1234?fmt=json. any help? thank you

Comment: Wow, the second question today trying to include the query string in URL routing based on django. It can't be done.

Comment: @Josh This is webapp, not Django.

Comment: @Nick, it's google-app-engine which is based on django - which is what I said in my comment (based on..).

Comment: @Josh App Engine is not based on Django. It bundles Django for convenience. The Python runtime also comes with 'webapp', a small framework which happens to make use of Django templates and forms. The routing is webapp's own, not Django's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't include the query parameter in the regex.

```
('/\d+',JsonHandler)

class JsonHandler(webapp.RequestHandler): 
  def get(self):
    if self.request.get("fmt") == "json": #check the query string in the get handler
      self.response.out.write("hello")
```